# How do I make it so that posts are "tagged" by checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, form-for

I'm using acts-as-taggable-on. I've tried multiple approaches but none of them work.

On the view:

```
    <%= check_box("post", "add_politics", {:class=> "post"}) %>
<%= f.label :politics %>

<%= check_box("post", "add_tech") %>
<%= f.label :tech, 'Technology' %>

<%= f.check_box :entertainment %>
<%= f.label :entertainment %>

<%= f.check_box :sports %>
<%= f.label :sports %>

<%= f.check_box :science %>
<%= f.label :science %>
    <%= f.submit %>
```

In the model:

```
  def add_politics; self.tag_list.add('politics'); end
  def add_tech; self.tag_list << 'tech'; end
  def add_entertainment;  self.tag_list << 'entertainment'; end
  def add_sports; self.tag_list << 'sports'; end
  def add_science; self.tag_list << 'science'; end
  def add_crime;  self.tag_list << 'crime'; end
  def add_business; self.tag_list << 'business'; end
  def add_social; self.tag_list << 'social'; end
  def add_nature; self.tag_list << 'nature'; end
  def add_other; self.tag_list << 'other'; end
```

In the controller:

```
 @post.tag_list << 'politics' if params[:post][:politics]
 @post.tag_list << 'tech' if params[:post][:tech]
 @post.tag_list << 'entertainment' if params[:post][:entertainment]
 @post.tag_list << 'sports' if params[:post][:sports]
 @post.tag_list << 'science' if params[:post][:science]
 @post.tag_list << 'crime' if params[:post][:crime]
 @post.tag_list << 'business' if params[:post][:business]
 @post.tag_list << 'social' if params[:post][:social]
 @post.tag_list << 'nature' if params[:post][:nature]
 @post.tag_list << 'other' if params[:post][:other]
```

What ends up happening is that only entertainment, sports, science...other get displayed because those are the ones that have <%=f.check_box :tag%> format. But unchecking or checking them doesn't make a difference -- those types of tags will always appear. What the heck is going on?

Comment: don't your hands hurt from typing the same code over and over again? try to refactor it a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Here's how:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'politics' %>
<%= f.label :politics %>

    <%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'tech' %>
<%= f.label :tech, 'Technology' %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'entertainment' %>
<%= f.label :entertainment %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'sports' %>
<%= f.label :sports %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'science' %>
<%= f.label :science %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'crime' %>
<%= f.label :crime %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'business' %>
<%= f.label :business %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'social' %>
<%= f.label :social %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'nature' %>
<%= f.label :nature %>

<%= check_box_tag 'tags[]', 'other' %>
<%= f.label :other %>
```

In the controller:

```
  @post.tag_list = params[:tags]
```

Comment: view could use some refactoring. it could be rewritten to 3 lines